# Angular js ng-click not firing for hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im trying to learn Angular. I created a simple view as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div>
     <table ng-repeat="d in Details">
       <tr>
         <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
         <td>{{d.Salary}}</td>
         <td><a href="#" ng-click="ShowDetail(d)">Select</a></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Controller:script.js

```
// Code goes here

    var MyModule=angular.module("MyApp",[]);

    var MyCtrl=function($scope){

      var Details=[
        {Name:'XXXX',Salary:40000},
        {Name:'YYYY',Salary:50000},
        {Name:'ZZZZ',Salary:60000},
        {Name:'AAAA',Salary:70000}
        ];

      $scope.Details=Details;

      var ShowDetail=function(detail){
        alert("You selected "+detail.Name+"Salary is "+detail.Salary);
      };
    }
MyModule.controller("MyCtrl",MyCtrl);
```

Problem is when I click on the hyperlink 'Select' hyperlink I dont see any event firing. Please help.

Comment: How do you know if it being called? Did you place a breakpoint? I suspect that it is called, but alert is in window scope, which is not available by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `var ShowDetail`, try using `$scope.ShowDetail`.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, your controller handles the interaction with view. So any events in your view is handled by the respective controller.

The view and controller are tightly coupled to each other via `$scope`. Thus, any variables, objects or event handlers must be exposed on `$scope` in order to access them in your view.

Since you are calling, `showDetail`, which is defined in your controller, is still a normal JS function, and not in the context of Angular. To use the same in your view, you need to expose it through `$scope`.

Thus your function should be declared as follows,

```
 $scope.showDetail = function() {
   // your logic goes here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Amar mentioned, use `$scope.ShowDetail` instead of `var` and add event.preventDefault () inside the function to make sure href doesnt fire.